# How to remove previous projects from work folder in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have deployed some projects in `tomcat7` and removed them from `webapps` as well as from `work` folder but when try to deploy some new project as a `war` `to webapps` it is not getting extracted and all the previous projects folder were existing in work folder which are costing some problem.

so please advise me how to completely remove older projects from tomcat7?

log file which refers to folder which does not even exist

```
   SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\netbeans_workspace\Servlets-DWR\build\web does not exist or is not a readable directory


Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\netbeans_workspace\Servlets-DWR\build\web does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4894)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Servlets-DWR] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost
[localhost].StandardContext[/Servlets-DWR]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [co
mp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:959)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5483)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\Sli
ngeLeaveNotifier.xml
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\netbeans_workspace\SlingeLeaveNotifier\build\we
b does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4894)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SlingeLeaveNotifier] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost
[localhost].StandardContext[/SlingeLeaveNotifier]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [co
mp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:959)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5483)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\docs
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\examples
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\host-manager
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\manager
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 13, 2012 2:38:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4251 ms
```

Regards

Comment: I'm not the expert using java, but just to be clear, did you stop the service to delete it?

Comment: do you use eclipse to run/stop tomcat or deploy projects in tomcat?

Comment: export project as a war file to tomcat webapps folder and run the server

Comment: Stop tomcat, delete all the projects you want to, then place the war in the webapps folder and after doing this start Tomcat!

Comment: no it doesnot help,i even restarted the system but same problem occurs

Comment: if i create the war file with different name which was not created previous it is getting extracted if i create war file on the same name previously deployed(these folders are not even present in webapps)than it is not getting extracted

Comment: @Learner did you try the steps that I have mentioned in my updated comment?

Comment: yes deleted all the previous project folder from work as well as wepapps but does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. delete the file called `Servlets-DWR.xml` that can be found under `tomcatHome/conf/Catalina/localhost`
2. copy you war file to the webapps directory
3. restart Tomcat

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are using netbeans as IDE?

Comment: no, previously using that but now using eclipse  Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: I have even deleted work folder but it creates the same with same previous projects

Comment: Do you have tomcat-7 as a project inside eclipse?

Comment: No Patton, i have it separately some where in the system

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13836/discussion-between-learner-and-patton)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved a similar problem today:

In `tomcatHome/conf/Catalina/localhost` I've got two app xml file.

Declared in each file there is a resource: the two resources had the same name.

I changed one of the two resources' name and everything works.

Comment: LOL, I really appreciate your effort but very late answer very late. :)

Comment: Thank you Shai, I know I was 5 months late, but someone may have the some problem and my 2 cents could help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't installed a Tomcat7 on my work computer but I looked up in my Tomcat6. In the program folder should exitst a webapps folder and maybe a work folder. Go into the last one and search for your application. Apparently the server extract your war file into this.

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat directory you can find conf/context.xml file with deploys descriptions in another locations.
If you starting Tomcat from IDE, for example from Eclipse, you can find configuration of application and work directory in Server view.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem, because the file "tomcatHome/conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml" has some wrong configuration. The tag `<Context path="/app1" ......>`, you can find the content of the path isn't same to my project name. When I changed to the same, everything is ok.